# android - Google Sign In not working (no crashes or exceptions)

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-api-client, google-signin

I'm working on an app and I need it to have a Sign In activity. I have been following this (developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) and [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) and for some reason, everything is working just fine, no crashes, no error messages but no sign in as well.

But, every time I launch the activity I get these in the "Run" tab:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/n/armeabi-v7a
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/n/armeabi
```

and:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
```

and:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

and in the logcat I get:

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

But the wierd thing is I have the`google-services.json` in my `app` directory.

My project gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha7'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}}
```

My module:app gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "(My app ID)"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.3"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now here is my code (based in google's "Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App" tutorial):

```
public class Multiplayer extends AppCompatActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_multiplayer);

    // Views
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // [END build_client]

    // [START customize_button]
    // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
    // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
    // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
    // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
    // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
    // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
    // difference.
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    // [END customize_button]
} @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
// [END onActivityResult]

// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
// [END handleSignInResult]

// [START signIn]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signIn]

// [START signOut]
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END signOut]

// [START revokeAccess]
private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END revokeAccess]

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("LOADING");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
    if (signedIn) {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.comments).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText("SIGNED OUT");
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.comments).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;
        case R.id.disconnect_button:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

[Here is my folder structure (I did it as rakesh kashyap suggested)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k14tk.png)

Can someone help me? I can't seem to find the source of the problem.

Comment: check **google-services.json** file in app folder of your project if there is no file named **google-services.json** open this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/where-do-i-get-a-google-services-json

Comment: @HarishKamboj In the question, I have already mentioned that I have the google-services.json file in my Android app...

Comment: did you enabled google+ api ? from here : https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

Comment: @HarishKamboj Yes I have.

Comment: are you using FCM or GCM ?

Comment: @HarishKamboj I can't recall seeing any of these "Cloud messaging" things ever... How can I tell which one I'm using?

Comment: @user6181605  check your project gradle you are using 2 classpath for services...remove the one...not in use..and  see if sync error is still there...??

Comment: @user6181605 first make sure what cloud messaging  -fcm or  gcm are u using from your logcat I found out that you are using both together ? please be clear what u are using??

Comment: @PN10 I don't know what am I using

Comment: @PN10 I have tried every possible combination and only the current one is working...

Comment: @user6181605 are u new to android?in your gradle files u have included dependencies for gcm...is your application cross plateform??Would like to know from where u downloaded google-services.json?

Comment: @PN10 I'm new to android,  my app isn't cross platform and I downloaded it from the link Ruben suggested in his answer.

Comment: @user6181605 what sync error is there??Please specify that in your question ???Are u using latest version of stock avd emulator or other emulators??

Comment: @PN10 I'm using my own Nexus 5, and every error is in the question.

Comment: @user6181605's add your configuration details of..ur device...go in about phone section of your phone??u earlier told when u remove classpath for gcm-google -service u got sync error??

Comment: Since u are using 2 classpath ...your device is getting confused about which Google services..u are using.. & ur Google services version should be compatible.. With ur device configuration...so check..the details..

Comment: @PN10 I am pretty new with android, and I can't understand what you want me to do...

Comment: @Jehy's  in ur Nexus 5, go to settings->about phone..take a screenshot or copy paste all details which are present their in ur question... I mean edit ur question with details & See..u HV two classpath for Google services.. In ur questions isn't..it  in your project gradle??

Comment: Also add your AndroidManifest.xml..code here..

Comment: @PN10 you didn't send code, and I am updating

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by downloading and copying the google-services.json file for your Android app by following the steps below:

- Select your app/project name and Android packagename from this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android) and click Continue to Choose and configure services.
- Click Continue to Generate Configuration files.
- Download google-services.json and copy the file to the app/ or mobile/ module directory in your Android project.

Comment: In the question, I have already mentioned that I have the google-services.json file in my Android app...

Comment: @user6181605 delete already existing folder and try the above solution ..

Comment: @PN10 when I put apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  below apply plugin: 'com.android.application' and above android{ } It won't build the project and I get an error when syncing the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Check your build variant (Build -> select build variant). Make note of the variant name. Should be debug or release or what ever you have defined

Select project view. Navigate to app -> src and create a directory with the EXACT same name as your build variant.

copy your JSON file to this directory.

Try Build -> clean project. check gradle cosole. you should see something like this (Parsing json file: Drive:\path_to_your_app_dir\your_app_name\app\src\release_prod\google-services.json
)

Comment: Already copied there, although my build variant is Debug, should I change it to release?

Comment: can u post a screen shot of your folder structure and the json location

Comment: I have posted the folder structure.